# Week of year datetime object comparisons and returned values not correct

Tags: python

I was tinkering with `datetime.strptime()` and noticed something I find interesting with respect to week of year or `%W` :

```
from datetime import datetime as dt

dt.strptime('2018 30', '%Y %j') == dt.strptime('2018 22', '%Y %j')
False

dt.strptime('2018 8', '%Y %m') == dt.strptime('2018 10', '%Y %m')
False

dt.strptime('2018 30', '%Y %W') == dt.strptime('2018 22', '%Y %W')
True # wrong
```

The actual value returned for a specific `%W` is not useful as well:

```
dt.strptime('9-2016', '%j-%Y')
datetime.datetime(2016, 2, 3, 0, 0)

dt.strptime('9-2016', '%m-%Y')
datetime.datetime(2016, 9, 1, 0, 0)

dt.strptime('9-2016', '%W-%Y')
datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 1, 0, 0) # wrong
```

Conceptually, there is no difference between day, week, or month of a given year. For some reason `datetime.strptime()` responds to weeks differently than months or days.

Why does `datetime.strptime()` treat week-of-year differently than month-of-year or day-of-year when they are conceptually similar?

I have been pointed towards information given on this [page](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) yet I am still unable to determine the reasoning behind this behavior.

An excerpt from the liked page:

> Similar to %U and %W, %V is only used in calculations when the day of the week and the ISO year (%G) are specified in a strptime() format string. Also note that %G and %Y are not interchangeable.

But why would this be the desired behavior for weeks and not months `%m` or days `%j`?

Comment: If the ISO week number could be used without the ISO weekday, a convention would be needed as to what date must be returned (would it be Sunday of the week or Monday etc.). In addition to this, for symmetry `strptime` would need to accept ISO weekday without ISO week number, in which case probably the first week would be used, and that would often result in a date in the previous year and confuse everyone. Considering all this, I guess the devs made all parameters required so that anyone trying to parse an ISO week date would have to know for sure what they're doing.

Comment: @MikhailBurshteyn I did notice in the docs that the difference between `%U` and `%W` is what you mention in your first point.